# Cannot push changes in repo using Git

Tags: git, github, push, repo

$ git push -u origin main

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vertalQ/demo-repo2.git01~/': The requested URL returned error: 400

When I try to push changes to my GitHub repo, it pops up with that error. This is an attempt to start a new repo through the command line. I have set up an SSH key already but it still does not allow for access. Any possible reasons as to why this is the case?

Comment: More information regarding the issue: I have two repositories in VScode open in one file. I have followed all directions that GitHub has given me for starting a new repository through the command line. I hope this clears a few things up.

Comment: Looks like the URL for the remote is not correct (look at the closing `01~/`)

Comment: What does it show when you do `git remote -v`? I bet it shows a typo.

Answer (score 1):

`01~` in the URL looks suspicious. From my experience, such a GitHub URL is invalid. You can fix it if you remove that odd symbols.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/vertalQ/demo-repo2.git
```

I looked at https://github.com/vertalQ/, you don't seem to have `demo-repo2`. You might want

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:vertalQ/REPO2.git
```